# What is meant by Coulomb gauge not being Lorenz invariant?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, potential, inertial-frames, gauge

This question is in the context of QFT. The notes says:
A disadvantage of working in Coulomb gauge is that it breaks Lorentz invariance.
What is meant by Coulomb gauge not being Lorenz invariant?

The Coulomb gauge is just a constraint on $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ and thus it is independent of inertial frame.

I think I have an answer for my own question but I think I am completely wrong.
We can transform electric- and magnetic fields to different inertial frames. Maybe there also exists transformations between two different inertial frames for the potential fields ($\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$). Well we can find $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ that satisfy for example the Coulomb gauge in a frame $S$. Applying those transformations, to convert $\mathbf{A}$ and $\phi$ in inertial frame $S$ to inertial frame $S'$, we obtain the potential fields $\mathbf{A}'$ and $\phi'$ in the frame $S'$. $\mathbf{A}'$ and $\phi'$ probably does not satisfy the Coulomb gauge and thus the Coulomb Gauge is not Lorentz invariant. I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: You are right. Your understanding is correct.

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/coulomb-gauge-lorenz-invariant.1056573/

Comment: You say: "the notes says..." Can you specify which notes you are referring to?  Is this a published work somewhere?  Are they notes from a class?